# Change background colour in web using java

Tags: java, xhtml

I'm not sure if the title is correct as I'm not familiar with all the naming technologies. :)

Anyway, I would like to ask if it is possible to change a background colour of a field from a webpage using java.  Based from what I'm working on:

name.xhtml

```
<p:inputText id="name"
    value="FirstName"
    maxlength="20" />
</p:inputText>

<p:commandButton id="changeColour" value="changeColour"
    actionListener="#{user.change}"
    update="name" >
</p:commandButton>
```

user.java

```
public final void change() {
    Some code here to change background colour???
}
```

Is this even possible? thank you..

Comment: how about javascript or jquery?

Comment: Yes it is possible use JSP for calling the change()

Comment: Guessing you are using `JSF`, and it can possible to change desired ui component's style on `ActionListener` method in backing bean.